# Attaching drag behaviour without using data().enter() in D3 v4.0.0-alpha.40

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a project with a draggable circle. In the process of upgrading from D3 **v3** > **v4.0.0-alpha.40** the drag behaviour broke. It only seems to work when the draggable element is created using `data([1]).enter().append('circle')`. See the [simple jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/xgcycpka/2/) for a simplified version

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit 1**: [Github issue opened](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2829)

**Edit 2**: [Working jsfiddle as per accepted answer](https://jsfiddle.net/xgcycpka/4/)

Comment: After sifting through the code and pondering over it for a while, I'd consider it a bug. Remember that v4 is still alpha. Please consider opening an issue on github for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is copied from [my response to your issue](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2829#issuecomment-219786886).] This is the expected behavior, though perhaps it could be improved. As the documentation for [*drag*.subject](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag_subject) says:

> The default subject is the [datum](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_datum) of the element in the originating selection (see [*drag*](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#_drag)) that received the initiating input event. When dragging circle elements in SVG, the default subject is the datum of the circle being dragged…

And:

> If the subject is null or undefined, no drag gesture is started for this pointer; however, other starting touches may yet start drag gestures.

In your failing example, the datum of your circle is undefined, so it can’t initiate a drag gesture. Giving the circle a non-null datum, such as 1, fixes it.

Yet even your non-failing example isn’t ideal because the drag gesture can’t infer the *x*- and *y*-coordinates of the circle, and so when you start a drag gesture, the circle center will jump to the mouse (or touch) position, rather than maintaining the relative position of the circle and pointer. A better way of creating a single, draggable circle would be:

```
d3.select("svg").append("circle")
    .datum({x: 4 * 30, y: 4* 30})
    .attr("r", 30)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

It’s possible we should change the default subject to be something else if the element’s datum is undefined… such as the element itself. That would make the drag behavior work as you expect, although the above code is a better solution in my opinion.

Comment: thx mate! I'm new to d3, so I'll leave the discussion of what works and what doesnt until ive had a play

Comment: @mbostock Nice explanation! The behaviour itself feels quite odd, though. To me this looks like taking the data-driven approach one step too far. I think, this is very counter-intuitive and will give rise to a bunch of questions similar to this one. Wouldn't anyone expect to act on elements when `.call()`ing the drag behaviour on a selection (of elements). Why shouldn't you be able to drag elements around, which got no data bound to them. Could you please shed some light on this; I'd be happy to get to know the rationale behind it.

Comment: I’ve changed the behavior in a more recent release to allow dragging by default even if there is no associated data. As of release 0.1.5 the default subject if there is no data is an {x, y} object representing the initial position of the pointer when the drag gesture starts.

Answer (score 2):

When first tackling this problem I encountered two problems, which thwarted my plans of attack. But as the development of v4 progresses Mike Bostock has cleared the way:

1. The first problem was the missing fallback to the element itself if there is no data present (removed by commit [`8b25a53`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/commit/8b25a53c826200fe643cd009fe9fd0ad8e99085b#diff-20e0bc424c1a2054325b0d8cf1ccd580)). My originial answer (see below) solved this by explicitely setting the element to be the subject of the drag. This was addressed by [issue #18](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/issues/18) and was reverted by commit [`4e4855f`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/commit/4e4855fd8ee63fa9634686ed4d232a2dcade9cf1), thus eliminating the need to set the subject.
2. Looking at it again, I realized that the properties `dx` and `dy` got removed from the `DragEvent`. I opened [issue #21](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/issues/21) asking Mike if we could have them back. Fortunately, he agreed and brought them back with commit [`24e9583`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/commit/24e958381d0c2df0db22decef4cdab3f4b25a391).

The missing links are now available in the latest build for version v4.0.0-alpha.44.

That said, I was ready to implement the *no data* approach I thought of in the first place:

```js
d3.selectAll("circle")
    .call(d3.drag()
            .on("drag", function() {
              this.transform.baseVal
                .appendItem(this.ownerSVGElement.createSVGTransform())
                .setTranslate(d3.event.dx, d3.event.dy);
              this.transform.baseVal.consolidate();
            })
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.44.js"></script>

<svg width="300" height="300">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="blue"/>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

The solution uses standard SVG transformations to translate the elements which got the drag behavior attached to them. It creates a new [`SVGTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform), appends it to the elements [`SVGTransformList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/SVGTransformList), sets the translation's values to the `DragEvent`s relative `dx` and `dy` coordinates and consolidates the transformation list for the sake of brevity.

This even circumvents the the jumps Mike Bostock mentioned in the second part of his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37284309/4235784), which are caused since the position of the element relative to the mouse pointer could not be inferred.

---

**Obsolete:** *As the development of v4.0 evolves, the original answer is no longer valid. It was meant for versions 4.0.0-alpha.40 and below.*

<strike>As Mike Bostock mentioned the handling of the drag's *subject* was changed by commit [`8b25a53`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/commit/8b25a53c826200fe643cd009fe9fd0ad8e99085b#diff-20e0bc424c1a2054325b0d8cf1ccd580). The commit's comment states:</strike>

> #### Simpler default subject.
>
> Don’t fallback to the originating element if the datum is undefined. If you want to use the originating element
>   as the subject, make it explicit.

And, of course, you are free to "*make it explicit*" to get a solution for your problem. Because the drag's subject no longer defaults to the element if there is no data bound to it, you need to explicitely set the subject yourself by calling [`drag.subject()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag_subject). If you want it to always refer to the element rather than to the data you could simply use a callback returning `this`.

```
d3
  .select("svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended)
    .subject(function(d) { return this; }))  // Explicitely set the subject to the element
```

Or, if you want it to default to any data bound and fallback to the element if no such data is available, you would be using:

```
d3
  .select("svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended)
    .subject(function(d) { return d == null ? this : d; }))
```

This is actually the same logic as it was before it got removed. Have a look at updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgcycpka/5/) for a working example.